# create list template from list in SharePoint online & download the template using CSOM in Powershell 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, csom

Trying to create a `list template` from custom list using Powershell in SharePoint online and trying to download the template on my local machine.

How to create list template  achieve above requirement

**Updates** in question :-  How to create list template using client side object model in PowerShell? 
suggest links..

Answer (score 0):

```
$site = get-spsite("http://testsite")
$web = $site.RootWeb
$list = $web.Lists["Announcements"]
SharePoint $list.SaveAsTemplate() PowerShell Command use following parameters.
$list.SaveAsTemplate(“Template Name”,”Template Title”,”Template Description”,1)
```

In the forth parameter of `SaveAsTemplate()`, if you want to save the specified site as template along with data use 1, otherwise use 0.

```
Eg:- $list.SaveAsTemplate("TestListTemplate.stp", "TestListTemplate", "Test List Template", $false)
```

Source : [Creating a List template from a list with PowerShell](https://hpksanje.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/saving-a-list-as-a-list-template-creating-lists-from-custom-template-using-powershell/)

Comment: is above script work for SharePoint online ?

Comment: you need to try it out, this is actually for 2010

Comment: yes i have try this script ,  not working for SharePoint online

Comment: can we save list template using csom , if yes please suggest some links

Answer (score 0):

Based on myknowledge, it’s not feasible to export lists and libraries in SharePoint Online using PowerShell.

For detailed information about the cmdlets for SharePoint Online, please see:

[Introduction to the SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-the-SharePoint-Online-Management-Shell-c16941c3-19b4-4710-8056-34c034493429?CTT=1&CorrelationId=6562a910-461f-40e2-a41d-a79d7c3fa4d1&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#_Toc338150378).

Basically using CSOM you can create lists using already existing custom templates, but programmatically you cannot create new ones as SaveAsTemplate method is not exposed in CSOM API.

To create a list from existing custom template below is the code.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl");
var web = context.Web;
context.Load(web,s => s.ListTemplates );
context.ExecuteQuery();
var listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation
{
Title = "My Jobs",
Description = "This is the job list description"
};
var listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(template => template.Name == "Jobs");
listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
listCreationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;
site.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: yes , you are right..        so please suggest some CSOM in powershell links,

Comment: please see my updated answer

Comment: Amit thanks for above code, give me links where i can see code for create list template using list in SharePoint online using CSOM in PowerShell

Comment: as u sated that "SaveAsTemplate method is not exposed in CSOM API.",so please give me some articles, for your statements....